How can I use rows and columns orientation in the same page in a Flexdashboard? will be rendered using rshiny
I'd like to create the layout below, but haven't found a way to do it. The idea is to have a row to allocate cards with big numbers, a column that will contain the main table and the another column splited into two row to allocate the charts











Value Box



Sidebar
-------------------------------------
--------------------------------------



Main Table
Chart 1









------------------------------------




Chart 2








That is my code was built based on rows orientation

How about something like this:
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
    vertical_layout: fill
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
```
Inputs {.sidebar}
------------------------------------------------------------------

**This is the sidebar from which you can control your dashboard**

Row {data.height=650}
----------------------------------------------------------------------
### ValueboxA

```{r}
library(flexdashboard)
valueBox(50, caption = "Errors",icon = "fa-thumbs-down")
```

### ValueboxB
```{r}
library(flexdashboard)
valueBox(107, caption = "Trials", icon="fa-tag")

```

### ValueboxC
```{r}
library(flexdashboard)
valueBox(247, caption = "Connections", icon="fa-random")
```
---------------------------------------------------------

Column {data-width=60}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart A

```{r}

```

Column {data-width=40}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart B

```{r}

```

### Chart C

```{r}

```


Hope it helps!
